# Inserted array into a GTK.Grid

Tags: python, arrays, pygtk

I created an interface with glade:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk


class Avvio:

    Nome1=["Filippo","Giordano","44","21/06/1955","Impiegato","445554"] 
    Nome2=["Andrea","Camilli","22","21/05/1990","Studente","656547"] 
    def accedi(self):
        print("ciao")

    def cancella(self,button):
        print("Cancella elementi")

def build_window():
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file("Lista.glade")
    builder.connect_signals(Avvio())
    win=builder.get_object("window1")
    return win

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = build_window()
    win.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

I have two arrays:

```
Nome1=["Filippo","Giordano","44","21/06/1955","Impiegato","445554"] 
Nome2=["Andrea","Camilli","22","21/05/1990","Studente","656547"]
```

I would like to insert arrays into a GTK.Grid, created under glade file. For each field of the table associated an element of the array.

Is it possible?

I used GTK.Grid.attach(), but didn't work.

PS This is a glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="width_request">900</property>
    <property name="height_request">400</property>
    <property name="can_focus">True</property>
    <property name="modal">True</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid" id="griglia">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="margin_left">10</property>
        <property name="margin_right">10</property>
        <property name="margin_top">10</property>
        <property name="row_homogeneous">True</property>
        <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Esci</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">start</property>
            <property name="valign">center</property>
            <property name="margin_left">10</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">3</property>
            <property name="top_attach">6</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Cancella Tutto</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="opacity">0.98999999999999999</property>
            <property name="halign">start</property>
            <property name="valign">center</property>
            <property name="margin_left">10</property>
            <signal name="pressed" handler="cancella" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">3</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
            <property name="width">1</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
            <property name="width_request">0</property>
            <property name="height_request">0</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="shadow_type">in</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkViewport" id="viewport1">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <child>
                  <object class="GtkGrid" id="grid2">
                    <property name="visible">True</property>
                    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                    <property name="border_width">3</property>
                    <property name="column_homogeneous">True</property>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="Nome">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Nome</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="left_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="width">1</property>
                        <property name="height">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="Cognome">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Cognome</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="left_attach">1</property>
                        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="width">1</property>
                        <property name="height">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="Età">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Età</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="left_attach">2</property>
                        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="width">1</property>
                        <property name="height">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="Data">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Data di Nascita</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="left_attach">3</property>
                        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="width">1</property>
                        <property name="height">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="Profes">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Professione</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="left_attach">4</property>
                        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="width">1</property>
                        <property name="height">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkCheckButton" id="Tutti">
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Sel. Tutti</property>
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="receives_default">False</property>
                        <property name="xalign">0</property>
                        <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="left_attach">6</property>
                        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="width">1</property>
                        <property name="height">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                    <child>
                      <object class="GtkLabel" id="Matricola">
                        <property name="visible">True</property>
                        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                        <property name="label" translatable="yes">Matricola</property>
                      </object>
                      <packing>
                        <property name="left_attach">5</property>
                        <property name="top_attach">0</property>
                        <property name="width">1</property>
                        <property name="height">1</property>
                      </packing>
                    </child>
                  </object>
                </child>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
            <property name="width">3</property>
            <property name="height">7</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label8">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Inserimento Dati in Tabella</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">7</property>
            <property name="width">4</property>
            <property name="height">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```